# What is the theory behind the event process loop in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm looking at this gist describing a file walk algorithm in JavaScript

```
// ES6 version using asynchronous iterators, compatible with node v10.0+

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

async function* walk(dir) {
    for await (const d of await fs.promises.opendir(dir)) {
        const entry = path.join(dir, d.name);
        if (d.isDirectory()) yield* walk(entry);
        else if (d.isFile()) yield entry;
    }
}

// Then, use it with a simple async for loop
async function main() {
    for await (const p of walk('/tmp/'))
        console.log(p)
}
```

and I'm blown away by the impulse (of the language features, not the author) to shove async / await in every crevice of the algorithm. I don't understand that well the architecture of Node.js, but I assume there is some intention behind the heavily asynchronous nature? It's pretty confusing and new to me coming from a primarily declarative procedural C/C++ thread / process model. I'm wondering not "what's the model" or "is it better" as one might have an opinion on, but rather "what's the idea driving the asynchronicity?" Is this a relic of browser's need for responsiveness over generic task based efficiency?

My question is "why so much asynchronicity?". I'm not looking for an opinion, I'm looking for someone with knowledge of Node.js or JavaScript's history and evolution to explain it's architecture.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/8691344

Answer (score 1):

> Like, it can be less efficient, we don't care, we just need the person sitting in front of the screen not to lose focus while we're rendering the N million elements on the page?

Well, at the high level, the first part of that sentence and the second part of the sentence are in conflict.  If the server is inefficient, then it won't be able to be properly responsive to a bunch of client requests that arrive around the same time.  So, you WANT to make your server efficient so it can be as responsive as possible to client requests.

---

Now, we need to back up a few steps and understand what's really going on in the code you show.  First off, while the language happens to be Javascript, the core logic of that code and how it's using `async`, `await` and generators is not just because of Javascript the language.  It's because of the specific environment that the Javascript is running, in this case nodejs.

That environment uses an event loop and runs a single thread of Javascript.  Other OS threads are used for various system things and some library implementations, but when nodejs runs your Javascript, it is only running one piece of Javascript at a time (single threaded).

Meanwhile, when you design a server, you want it to be responsive to lots of incoming requests.  You don't want it to have to process one request and make all other requests wait until that first one is done before it starts working on the next one.  But, the nodejs event loop model doesn't use multiple threads and thus doesn't directly run multiple requests handlers at the exact same time.

The solution nodejs deploys comes from the fact that for a large variety of server request handlers, the predominant activity and what takes most of the time to process the request is I/O (like networking, file I/O or database I/O).  Those are lower level operations that have their own (non-Javascript) implementation.

So, it deploys an asynchronous model for all I/O operations.  A well written server can start an asynchronous I/O operation and while that it processing (not in code the nodejs interpreter itself is running), the interpreter and the nodejs event loop are then free to do other things, to work on another request.  Some time later when that asynchronous operation completes, an event will get inserted into the event loop and when the interpreter finishes whatever it was in the middle of doing, it can then process the result from that asynchronous operation and continue that operation.

In this way, Javascript executes only in a single thread, but many incoming requests can be "in process" at the same time.

Yes, this is a completely different model from your old school C/C++ threaded model.  You either learn this different model to write efficient and effective server code in nodejs or you don't.  If you want to stick with the old model, then pick a different environment that runs request handlers in threads (Java, C++, etc...) and is designed to do that well (with, of course, the associated design and testing overhead of getting all your multi-threaded concurrency correctly written and thoroughly tested).

A big benefit to the nodejs model is it is not vulnerable to many of the concurrency issues that multi-threaded execution models are.  There are short-comings to the nodejs model too that need work-arounds occasionally.  For example, if you have CPU-heavy code in a request handler written in Javascript, then that can still bog things down and one needs to find a way to get that CPU-heavy stuff out of the main event loop into some other thread or process (perhaps even a work queue).  But, I/O is all asynchronous and can stay in the main thread without bogging anything down.

> Maybe I'm old school (academic CS background, mostly a C/C++ kernel guy), but what benefit does this confer?

The less code that needs to be in separate, concurrent threads, the less concurrency bugs you are likely to have and the code is far, far easier to fully test.

> Why would I want an asynchronous loop?

Well, you want a loop because you're trying to loop over something.  You want to use asynchronous operations in that loop either when you don't want to block the event loop or when that's the only type of operation you have to complete your task (such as doing a lookup in a database).

> How would I know, as the developer, if I've even optimized something?

Using asynchronous operations isn't about optimizing something.  It's about core design to write good server code and to not block the event loop.  And, in fact, may interfaces in nodejs such as a database interface or a network interface will ONLY offer an asynchronous interface.

The way you ask this question suggests that you would benefit from understanding much better the core nodejs architecture and reading a lot more about how the event loop works and how asynchronous I/O operations work.

> Is this just about responsiveness?

Well, first off, if you're using APIs that are only asynchronous (like with networking or databases), you don't have any choice.  You're going to be doing an asynchronous code design to use that API.  If you have a choice for whether to use an asynchronous or synchronous API (like you do with the file system access in nodejs), then you're choosing whether to block the event loop or not block the event loop on every API call.  If you block the event loop, you will be massively compromising the scalability and responsiveness of your server.

---

> I'm blown away by the impulse (of the language features, not the author) to shove async / await in every crevice of the algorithm.

That particular code example does attempt to use the kitchen sink of asynchronous language features all in the same implementation with `async`, `await`, generators and `yield`.  I do not generally do that.  The point of that implementation is to be able to create an interface that can be used fairly simply like this:

```
for await (const p of walk('/tmp/')) {
    ...
}
```

while the internals of `walk()` are asynchronous.  This implementation hides nearly all of the asynchronous implementation complexity from the user of the API and that makes the API easier to code with.  With a single `await` in the right place, the user of the API can almost code as if it was synchronous.  Making asynchronous operations easier to code with are what these Javascript language features (promises, async, await, generators, etc...) are for.

**Advantages of Event Loop Model**

*Simplicity of programming.*  You generally don't have to deal with concurrency issues when accessing shared data from threads since all your Javascript runs in the same thread so all shared data access is from the same thread.  You don't need mutexes for accessing shared data.  You don't run any risk of deadlocks from those mutexes.

*Fewer Bugs.*  Accessing common data from threads is much more difficult to write bug-free code.  The code can be subject to race conditions or missing concurrency protections if not written perfectly.  And, these race conditions are often hard to test for and may not show themselves until your server gets under high load and even then won't be easily reproducible.

*Higher Scalability (in some situations).*  For code that is predominantly I/O bound, the cooperative event loop model may result in higher scalability.  This is because each request in process does not result in a separate OS thread and the overhead that it adds.  Instead, there's just a small amount of application state, often in a closure associated with the next callback or promise its waiting for.

**Articles about Event Loop Programming**

[Why the Cool Kids Use Event Loops](https://chronicle.software/why-the-cool-kids-use-event-loops/) - This happens to be about using event loops in Java programming, but the discussion applies to any environment

[The Case of Threads vs Events](https://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/043_threadsevents.html)

Comment: "If the server is inefficient, then it won't be able to be properly responsive to a bunch of client requests that arrive around the same time."

A concurrent algorithm could accomplish everything in aggregate much slower but otherwise be more responsive in the near team. It's not computational efficacy it's just better task division. So clearly there's nuance to what we mean here by "efficiency" as completing the bulk of requisite tasks in a certain time frame vs. quickly responding to user requests. That's not the same thing. It's less efficient to logically parallelize this stuff.

Comment: This just reads like I initially supposed - one event processing loop, as much deferred processing as possible. My real question is "what's the point of that model"? Which I have no idea why that is considered "opinion based". I am supposed to believe there is no answer to the question of why node.js is designed with this model? Yea I don't get it, I'm new, that's why I asked. Obviously it was designed like that for a reason, and I'm trying to understand that. Or I suppose it's just spurious and random so I shouldn't ask such questions here because they "opinion" based. Because no one knows.

Comment: @Spencer - I voted to reopen, but we need more reopen votes.  For now, just ignore the close votes as I see you've already modified your title and we can continue here.  I look for useful ways to answer that are not just opinion.  Others look for any sign of opinion in the question as a reason to try to get rid of it (it's a common thing here).  Clearly all the specific questions in your question (the ones I've addressed in my answer) are not about opinion which to me makes it an answerable question.

Comment: @spencer - There are several points in my answer about the advantages of the single event loop model.